# Adding a Button to a JFace Table Cell - Mapping

Tags: java, mapping, swt

I am using a ColumnLabelProvider for my TableViewer Columns.  The last column is set up for a button. This is the code for my

```
case 7: {
    Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Object, Button>();   
    TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
    Button button;
    String filename = (((AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) element).getFileDir() + "/" + ((AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) element).getfileName());
    if(buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement())) {
        button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
    } else {
        button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.PUSH);
        button.setImage(appReg.getImage("PDFViewerLabel.ICON"));
        button.setData("file.id", filename);
        buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);
    }
    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
    editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
    editor.grabVertical = true;
    editor.setEditor(button , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new SelectionListener(item, button, cell.getElement()));
    editor.layout();
    break;
}
```

My question:
why do you have to have the map?
I am trying to figure the purpose of the map there.
Seems like you could just create the button without the map.

Comment: `button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());` this line uses the `Map`. Have a look at it and take a guess what it's used for.

Comment: I assumed it was to keep from having the same button in every row.

Comment: It's used to keep track of the `Button` of each cell. With the map, you can get the exact button of each cell, which makes handling press events easier.